# RingBuffer for data collection

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a Ring Buffer implementation that I like to use to process an incoming data. Is the following approach safe and efficient to use considering synchronizations needed?.

```
void CMyDlg::MyButton1()
{
    RingBuffer BufRing(10000);

    unsigned char InputBuf[100];
    unsigned char OutBuf[100];

    for (int ii = 0; ii < 1000; ++ii)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            InputBuf[i] = i;
        }

        BufRing.Write(InputBuf,100);

        BufRing.Read(OutBuf,100);
        AfxBeginThread(WorkerThreadProc,OutBuf,THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,0,0,NULL);
    }
}

UINT WorkerThreadProc( LPVOID Param )
{
    unsigned char* pThreadBuf = (unsigned char*)Param;

    for (int c = 0; c < 100; ++c)
    {
        TRACE("Loop %d elemnt %x\n",c,pThreadBuf[c]);
    }


    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: This question would make more sense if you showed the implementation of RingBuffer.  Does it include internal synchronization?  Does it copy the input buffer into itself or simply maintain a pointer to the buffer?

Answer (score 1):

Looks hazardous to me...

```
void CMyDlg::MyButton1()
{
    // ...
    unsigned char OutBuf[100];

    for (int ii = 0; ii < 1000; ++ii)
    {
        // ...

        BufRing.Read(OutBuf,100);
        AfxBeginThread(WorkerThreadProc,OutBuf,THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,0,0,NULL);
    }
}
```

The problem that I see is that you're using a single buffer (`OutBuf`) to store data in, passing it to a worker thread, and then modifying that same buffer in the next iteration of your loop.

Your test code won't reveal this, because you're simply repopulating `OutBuf` with the same values in every iteration (as far as I can tell, anyway). If you changed `InputBuf[i] = i;` to `InputBuf[i] = ii;` and included a unique thread ID in your `TRACE` output, you'd probably see suspicious behaviour.

Comment: tried to practice on this method, came across this site (with elegant code): http://soundprogramming.net/programming_and_apis/creating_a_ring_buffer I allocated large buffer then tried to write and read 100 bytes consecutively.  can I see the improved version that works.